# undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, posts

I'm trying my first RoR project and all was going well, but now I've got into a bit of a mess with creating posts that admin users are only supposed to be able to do, and each post has a topic. I'm getting a undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass error and no matter what I change I can't seem to solve it. Spent hours and hours on it! Like I said, i'm new and I know things are wrong, I also changed things about to relate to another users questions but still doesn't function, any help much appreciated! Thanks!

My admin model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :trackable, :timeoutable, :registerable, :authentication_keys => [:email]

has_many :posts
has_many :topics, :through => :posts
end
```

My post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin 
  belongs_to :topic 
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :admin_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
  #before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

#post is valid only if it's associated with a topic:
validates :topic_id, :presence => true
#can also require that the referenced topic itself be valid
#in order for the post to be valid:

validates_associated :topic

  end
```

My topic model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end
```

my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :authenticate_admin!
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :has_topic, :only =>[:new, :create]

def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def new
  @post = @topics.posts.build
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id1])
end

#Issues GET request at /posts/1
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

#Issues GET request at /posts/1/edit
def edit          
end    

#Issues POST request at /posts
  def create

@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)
@current_user.posts << @post
#@topic.posts << @post

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "post created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render '/'
  end
end

#Issues DELETE request /posts/1
def destroy
    @post.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Post deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  protected

    def has_topic
      unless(@topic =Topic.find_by_id(params[:topic_id]))
            flash[:warning] = 'post must be for an existing topic'
          end
        end

  private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

# Never trust parameters from the internet, only allow the white list through. 
#:topic_id  
def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:id, :content, :admin_id)
end
 end
```

Like I mentioned before, I had one version of all my own code, which had the same problem, I tried adapting it by using some code from another question post (just temporarily-a friend recommended it to try and find the error) but still having the same problem. I've created users, admins and posts (via console). I've also tried changing part of create to @post = @admin.posts.build(post_params) etc, just to see if anything works. I've been trying this for so long that i've just got confused with it all, go easy on me ! Many thanks!

Sorry I forgot to say... the error comes from the Create method.

```
@post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)
        @current_user.posts << @post
```

Comment: Please tell us which line you are getting the error. As of now it is really confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting is that you are calling .posts on an object that is nil. Given that you call .posts on two objects in your CREATE method:

```
@post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)
@current_user.posts << @post
```

And you set @topic in a before filter, I'd suggest that `@current_user` is nil. The standard is to use `current_user` so I'd suggest removing the `@` sign or setting `@current_user` to something.

If it's on the NEW action, you set:

```
@post = @topics.posts.build
```

Where you don't actually set `@topics`. Suggest that you set this to something or remove the 's' and use the `@topic` that you set in your before filter

Comment: Lines '@post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)' and '@current_user.posts << @post' if I remove the first line, show the same error in the create method. I've taken the @ off the current_user and actually tried deleting the before_filter altogether. Still getting the same error, I'm sure it's something i'm doing but my brain is so fried from looking at this so long, I can't even make logic of it all! Really appreciate the help and sorry for my noobiness! :)

Comment: If you could explain exactly where I'm going wrong and why, that would be great for my learning. I must of been fiddling with this for about 7 hours now, crazy as it sounds! Appreciate it very much

Comment: Hi @Yule any chance of a follow up please if you haven't seen this? Many thanks!

Comment: The thing you're doing wrong is calling a method on a nil object. You need to define every variable before you do anything with it. Try installing better_errors and using the repl to inspect each variable to see which is nil (I expect current_user) then define this somewhere

Comment: ok thanks @Yule, so i've done that. Just to try and get it working even once, I now have... 
`@topic = Topic.find_by(id: 2)`  as that topic relates to the current_admin i'm using.  
`current_admin.posts << @topic.posts.build(params[:post])`   followed by
`@post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)` and 
`current_admin.posts << @post`        

Now I have the error  `undefined method `posts' for #<Topic:0x007fbb196987b0>` on the line 
`current_admin.posts << @topic.posts.build(params[:post])`  under create method also

I've also confirmed the @topic and current_admin variable's are set. Any idea's.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in your `new` method

```
def new
  @post = @topics.posts.build
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id1])
end
```

You didn't initialised `@topics` and you are using it in this line `@post = @topics.posts.build`.

You need to change your `new` method to

```
def new
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @post = @topic.posts.build
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the error you're referencing is in your `create` action, where you call `@post = @topic.posts...` which can throw a `NoMethodError` because `@topic` is unset, but your question doesn't actually say which line is causing the error, which is a big problem for those of us trying to help you.

Comment: He has a `before_filter` for `@topic`.

Comment: Which only throws a warning into the flash if it doesn't exist, it won't ensure that `@topic` isn't `nil`.  It's a fair point though and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Pavan I've updated my question, sorry about that! yes the error is in the create action, i've tried some more things suggested but still no luck. Where and how is best to set the topic? Again, I'm sure these are stupid questions but really just trying to learn. It's the post/topic relations that are really confusing me. As it's for admins that i'm setting this up for, I'm now using current_admin which has a value. Many thanks!